# I forgot to validate my student visa in France. Can I leave?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, france

I didn’t validate my 6 month student visa in France after 3 months. I fly to Amsterdam and have a 17 hour lay over in which I’ll leave the airport and stay in an air bnb, and then I fly home to Canada. What should I expect? Will I be deported or fined? I’ve tried researching what happens but the rules just say I can’t return to France. But can I travel to another Schengen country of it means I’m leaving Europe?

Comment: Please do update us after your trip with what happens when you make your trip.

Answer (score 20):

Better late than never is probably the best advice that can be given.

Since it can be done online, just do it, print out the sent pdf and take it with you.

---

> **Validate your visa**
>   If your visa bears the mention "Dispense temporaire de carte de séjour"
>
> - You have nothing to do.
>
> If your visa bears the mention "Carte de séjour à solliciter..."
>   You have to ask for a residence permit upon arrival at the 'Préfecture', as explained below.
>
> Otherwise, if your visa bears the mention "Passeport Talent", "**Etudiant**" or is listed on the following page
>   Within the first 3 months following your arrival in France, as soon as you have a fixed address, go to the website of the **[General Directorate of Foreign Nationals](https://administration-etrangers-en-france.interieur.gouv.fr/)** to validate your visa.
>
> This procedure is mandatory, you will need your passport to complete it.
>
> Also, you will have to pay a resident permit tax online by credit card (during the procedure or on https://timbres.impots.gouv.fr), or in a bureau de tabac by credit card or cash (ask for a timbre fiscal électronique “Titre pour étrangers”).
>
> At the end of this procedure, a confirmation of the validation in PDF format (« Confirmation de la validation de l’enregistrement de votre visa long séjour valant titre de séjour »), will be sent to you by [e]mail.
>   We advise you to print and always keep this document with you as it can be required while you travel or to follow your administrative procedures (CAF, Assurance maladie/healthcare).
>
> For more information, please consult the dedicated FAQ of the General Directorate of Foreign Nationals web portal.

---

**Sources**:

- [Accueil international - Validating your visa / Applying for a residence permit in France](https://international.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/en/student/visa-and-residence-permits/validating-your-visa-applying-for-a-residence-permit-in-france/validating-your-visa-applying-for-a-residence-permit-in-france-584671.htm)
- [General Directorate of Foreign Nationals](https://administration-etrangers-en-france.interieur.gouv.fr/)